# React, Relay and Navigation

Tags: reactjs, navigation, react-native, redux, relay

I am just getting started with React-Native and Relay. So far everything works nicely, but I am having some trouble finding a nice way to handle the combination of Navigation and Relay.

I am using NavigationExperimental with Redux to store the current state of the navigation, no problems there. Nesting Relay fragments in the component hierarchy is also fine. But what I don't quite get, is how to handle scenes, that are "children of other scenes." Let's say, for example, I have a database with users, that can be friends with each other. The scenes the navigator can display would then be home and a friends profile.

A GraphQL query for this would be something like

```
query {
  user { 
    id, 
    name, 
    [...], 
    friends { 
      edges { 
        node { 
          id, 
          name, 
          [...] 
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and there'd be two components, Home and ProfileModal, each associated to a scene, where the id of the concrete user to display is stored by Redux during a navigator-push action.

The Home component exhibits a fragment on user, the ProfileModal one on friend. But, since the ProfileModal is not actually a child of the Home component but rather an independent scene, I don't want to call the ProfileModals fragment inside the home components (Also since this might lead to fetching a lot of unnecessary data).

On top of that, to make Relay accept that there is also a Redux store, the Redux container needs to be inside the Relay container, so I can't pass the friend to be displayed (stored by Redux) to Relay.

I hope, I've been able to describe the situation. Basically it's about components that are actually children of other components, but not so in the DOM.

One more thing that relates to the hierarchy, Redux is, I think, the best way to store any temporary data shared between scenes (which happens in the simplest of examples, e.g. create a new group and add friends to it in a second modal), so I don't quite want to get rid of Redux (or a Redux like store in a root component).

So, what's the best way, to go about this hierarchy?